# How to remember credentials on android Web App?

Tags: php, android, web, credentials

I designed an application for android (I used android studio), which actually has an embedded web site, which was made by me in php.
The first screen of the application is a login. I would like to know how I can do to make the system to remember the user name and password, as happens in most of the android applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably gonna need a `CookieManager` and `CookieSyncManager` to maintain sessions when making calls in your `WebView`.

check out the API reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot run a `.PHP` page on a `WebView` on `android`. `PHP` is `server-side` so it needs to have a server to interpretate and process `.PHP` files.

If your goal is to have your `android` app built with `HTTP` pages, I suggest you [Phonegap / Cordova](http://phonegap.com/). Take a look. There are many examples which uses Cache/Built-in storage to store variables.

Comment: in fact I have a running server. the web application redirects to no-ip